# MS Access VBA concatenation

Tags: vba, ms-access

this is my first time posting! So I created a database on ms access that helps in invoicing and helps to create and analyse data. I wanted to simplify it and add code to it. One of the modules that I created is the following one, it takes four numbers as input, three of them have a default value of 0, if they are anything other than zero then it is supposed to concatenate them. I believe( atleast hope) the module is correct, but when I add it to the form, it displays an error "?Name".
Thanks in advance! :-)
This is the code:

```
Function MultiApart(ApOne As Single, ApTwo As Single, ApThree As Single, ApFour As Single) As String
Dim a As String
Dim b As String
Dim c As String
Dim d As String
a = CStr(ApOne)
b = CStr(ApTwo)
c = CStr(ApThree)
d = CStr(ApFour)
MultiApart = a
If (ApTwo > 0@) Then MultiApart = MultiApart & ", " & b
If (ApThree > 0@) Then MultiApart = MultiApart & ", " & c
If (ApFour > 0@) Then MultiApart = MultiApart & ", " & d
End Function
```

Comment: What does _when I add it to the form_ mean? This is just a function. Where and how do you (intend to) use it?

Comment: For "anything other than zero", you should use `<>` which is the "not equal to" operator. So for example: `ApTwo <> 0` is True when `ApTwo` is any number other than 0 and is False when `ApTwo` is 0.

Comment: Edit question to show the expression that calls function. The function works. Did you place it in a general module? Make sure the module does not have same name as function.

Comment: Thanks June7, the module had the same name and that was the issue!
Regarding Gustav's question, I meant calling the function in the form, the form is a report that I print, basically it's the invoice.
Regarding Toddleson's reply, it does work at least in MS access.